# insheet and multiple-character delimiters in Stata

Tags: csv, delimiter, stata

I am trying to use `insheet` to load in a data set from a .csv file. The delimiter in the data set is, however, `","` (including the quotes) rather than simply a comma `,` . The top three lines in the .csv file would thus look something like this:

```
Name","Sex","Income
John","M","45000
Jane","F","20000
```

It appears that `insheet` does not allow for multiple-character delimiters - I get an error message that states that the "delimiter() option was incorrectly specified." Is there anyway to easy insheet data from a file like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution 1.**

Stata 13 has support for multi-character delimiters. The command is `import delimited`. See the manual [here](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/dimportdelimited.pdf#dimportdelimitedRemarksandexamples).

**Solution 2.**

Use `filefilter` before using `insheet`. For example:

```
filefilter "source-file" "destination-file", from("\Q,\Q") to(",") replace
```

This replaces your multi-character delimiter with a comma delimiter. Run `help filefilter`.

**Solution 3.**

Are you not able to do a `find/replace` with your favorite text editor before importing to Stata? Find `","` and replace with `,`, for example. Then use Stata's `insheet` command. A good text editor may be more flexible than pure Stata in this respect.

**Solution 4 (maybe).**

Have you checked `infix` and `infile`? I have no experience with these but they may be worth checking out.

Answer (score 2):

This is not especially good technique, but it underlines @Roberto Ferrer's point that several different solutions exist. First put your toy dataset into a file, and then read it in as one string variable. Here we respect the limit in Stata <13 of 244 characters; in Stata 13 you can have much longer string variables.

```
. infix str data 1-244 using test.dat
(3 observations read)
```

Now `split` the data into parts, parsing wth your separator. We need compound double quotes here protecting the literal double quotes.

```
. split data, p(`"",""')
variables created as string: 
data1  data2  data3

. l

     +----------------------------------------------+
     |                data   data1   data2    data3 |
     |----------------------------------------------|
  1. | Name","Sex","Income    Name     Sex   Income |
  2. |    John","M","45000    John       M    45000 |
  3. |    Jane","F","20000    Jane       F    20000 |
     +----------------------------------------------+
```

Take the variable names out of the first observation, `drop` that and then use `destring` to convert to numeric what can be converted.

```
. forval i = 1/3 {
2. rename data`i'  `=data`i'[1]'
3. }

. drop in 1
(1 observation deleted)

. destring, replace
data contains nonnumeric characters; no replace
Name contains nonnumeric characters; no replace
Sex contains nonnumeric characters; no replace
Income has all characters numeric; replaced as long
```